# Sharing Buffers (VAO/VBO) between Pyglet Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyglet

Pyglet "say" buffers/data such as VAOs, VBOs and shaders are by default shared between Window GL contexts but I've tried everything to share buffers between windows. Buffers I generate and assign data to when one of the windows is active cannot be read (isn't detected) by the other window.

I've tried only using Pyglet.gl binding (no PyOpenGL). Specifying `gl.current_context` as context argument when creating window and parsing this value using various methods like creating a new `Config()`.

As a side note I currently have two windows each assigned to the same screen (not explicitly stated, I assume it by default since my computer only has 1 screen) so the windows are using the same GPU.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use pyglet, but reading its [Windowing, Context configuration docs](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/windowing.html) the word "share" is a bit confussing.

If you use a unique, same gl-context, for every window then, obviously, all the windows have access to the same resources like VBO, textures, etc. This is likely you best option.

If you want *different* contexts (so as to for example some sort of multithread usage), but sharing the access to those resources, then the same docs tell about using a `Config.create_context(share)` method. But [this other doc](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/modules/gl.html#pyglet.gl.Config) tells that that method is deprecated an prefer using `CanvasConfig.create_context` instead.

Let's say you have created a window, passing a `config` or letting it to create a default one:

```
mywindow1 = pyglet.window.Window()
```

Take its config and context:

```
config1 = mywindow1.config
context1 = mywindow1.context
```

Use them to create a shared context:

```
context2 = config1.create_context(context1)
```

Create another window for this new context

```
window2 = pyglet.window.Window(context=context2)
```

I repeat I don't know pyglet. So likely you find a best approach.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL contexts are not tied to windows. However for legacy reasons, OpenGL contexts are created *using* a window (drawable context). Pyglet gives you access to a window's context through the `window.context` attribute. And when creating a window, you can specify a preexisting context to use for OpenGL operations on that window¹. You can use that for the context of further windows created.

```
import pyglet
win_a = pyglet.window.Window()
win_b = pyglet.window.Window(context=win_a.context)
```

`win_a` and `win_b` will then use the *same* OpenGL context. Note that this is different from OpenGL list (resource) sharing, where several distinct OpenGL contexts share a common set of data holding objects.

---

¹ – It should be noted, that this is an unneccessary constraint, because intercompatible OpenGL contexts and drawables (windows, PBuffers and such) can be freely mixed and matched.

Comment: I think my question wasn't concise enough so this isn't answering my question, though a useful answer. I have updated my question to my more specific problem.